# How to get proper WordPress admin url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have the plugin with folder/files and I am using the plugin in admin dashboard.

```
Folder: views
       actions.php
       client_register.php
```

And I created one menu like this

```
add_submenu_page("custom", "Client Registration", "New Client Site",'manage_options', "client_register", 'page_client_register');

if ( ! function_exists( 'page_client_register' ) ) {
    function page_client_register(){
        render_page_client_register();
    }
}
```

And I am able to call the `page_client_register` function (which is actually a independent php file) like this.
`http://127.0.0.1/wp-admin/admin.php?page=client_register`
This is possible because I created the menu.

How can I access other files similar to that way?
using `wp-admin/admin.php` url

If I directly call the files like `http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/plugins/<pluginname>/views/actions.php` it says Direct PHP ACCESS is not allowed in some cloud sites.

How can I access these files using `wp-admin/admin.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You get the concrete URL to admin.php by using the [admin_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/) function:

```
admin_url('admin.php'); # http(s)://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php
```

And in your concrete example you add the page query-info part:

```
$url = admin_url('admin.php?page=client_register');
wp_redirect($url); 
exit;
```

OR

```
admin_url( "client_reg_action.php?page=client_register"] )
admin_url( "admin.php?page=".$_GET["page"] )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I am trying like http://127.0.0.1/sparkignitepro/wp-admin/admin.php?page=client_reg_action but it says "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

Comment: For accessing "admin_url()" you have to login with  admin.

Comment: Yes, I already logged in admin panel, and I updated the description, can you check it please?

Comment: @SkyDev Just replace your page slug with "client_register" instead of  "client_reg_action"
This error is comes up because you enter wrong page slug

Comment: I get this url http://127.0.0.1/sparkignitepro/wp-admin/admin.php?page=client_reg_action.php when I use admin_url( "admin.php?page=client_reg_action.php" ) and this is not the correct url